# Protractor tests as part of jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, protractor, jenkins-pipeline

In running protractor with headless chrome as part of jenkins pipeline. It is just running the commands from sh file such as..
Webdriver-manager update
Webdriver-manager start
Protractor conf.js

Test runs fine and I can see that when a test case fails the build still shows green even though in the logs it shows that "Process exited with  error code 1".

What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you post the console output of your jenkins job to understand it better ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you place the content of the windows shell file directly in the build step of Jenkins. Since you are triggering the Protractor command in a shell file, Jenkins doesn't know the exit code of Protractor

[image]

Comment: May be , because If I send the commands in build replay in jenkins and if the test fails, it goes red, But when I added it to sh file to deploy then it started showing green.
I will try what you have mentioned..